# Procedure to remove duplicates in a table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

**Brief model overview:**

I have a `student` and a `course` tables. As it's many to many relation there is also a junction table `student_course` (`id_student`, `id_course`), with `unique` constraint on both columns (composite).

**The problem I want to solve:**

On account of a mistake, there is no a `unique` constraint on the `code` column of the `course` table. It should as `code` column should uniquely identify a `course`. As a result there are two rows in the `course` table with the same value in the `code` column. I want to remove that duplicate, check that there is no other duplicates and add a `unique` constraint on the `code` column. Without loosing relations with `student` table.

**My approach to solve the issue:**

I have create a procedure that should do what I want.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REMOVE_COURSES
  (
    v_course_code        IN VARCHAR2,
    v_course_price       IN VARCHAR2
  )
AS
  new_course_id  NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO course (CODE, PRICE) VALUES (v_course_code, v_course_price)
    RETURNING ID INTO new_course_id;
    FOR c_course_to_overwrite IN (SELECT *
                                  FROM course
                                  WHERE code = v_course_code AND id != new_course_id) LOOP

      UPDATE student_course SET id_course = new_course_id WHERE id_course = c_course_to_overwrite.id;
      DELETE FROM course WHERE id = c_course_to_overwrite.id;
    END LOOP;
  END REMOVE_COURSES;
/
```

**Main problem I want to solve:**

The procedure keeps giving me an error about `unique` constraint violation on `student_course` table. But I am really not sure how it's possible as I am using `new_course_id`, so there is no chance that in the junction table there are two rows with the same `id_student`, `id_course`. What do I need to fix ?

**Miscellaneous:**

I want to solve that issue using procedure only for learning purposes

**EDITED:**

```
    CREATE TABLE student (
      id          NUMBER        GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
      name        VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    ALTER TABLE student MODIFY ID
      GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);

    CREATE TABLE course (
    id          NUMBER        GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    code        VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    ALTER TABLE course MODIFY ID
      GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY (START WITH LIMIT VALUE);

    CREATE TABLE student_course (
      id_student NUMBER NOT NULL,
      id_course NUMBER NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id_student, id_course),
      CONSTRAINT student_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_student) REFERENCES student (id),
      CONSTRAINT course_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_course) REFERENCES course (id)
    );

    insert into student (name) values ('John');
    INSERT INTO course (ID, CODE) VALUES (1, 'C_13');
    INSERT INTO course (ID, CODE) VALUES (2, 'C_13');
    commit;
    INSERT INTO STUDENT_COURSE (ID_STUDENT, ID_COURSE) VALUES (1, 1);
    INSERT INTO STUDENT_COURSE (ID_STUDENT, ID_COURSE) VALUES (1, 2);
    commit;

CALL REMOVE_COURSES('C_13');

[23000][1] ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS_C0014983) violated ORA-06512: near "REMOVE_COURSES", line 8
```

Comment: Please include the complete error you are getting. All three table structures, including their constraints, plus some sample data might be useful; and is the new ID being set by a trigger and sequence (or is an identity column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than removing one of the duplicate codes, you're creating a *third* course with the same code, and trying to move all students on either of the old courses onto the new one. The error suggests you have students who are already enrolled on both of the old courses.

Your cursor loop query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM course
WHERE code = v_course_code AND id != new_course_id
```

That will find all junction records for *both* old versions of the code, and the update then sets *all* of those junction records to the same new ID.

If there are any students listed against both old IDs for the code - which would be allowed by your composite unique key -  then they will both be updated to the same new ID.

So say the courses you're looking at are [updated for your example code]:

```
ID  CODE
--  ----
 1  C_13
 2  C_13
```

and you have junction records for a student for both courses, like:

```
ID_STUDENT  ID_COURSE
----------  ---------
         1          1
         1          2
```

You are creating a new course:

```
ID  CODE
--  ----
 3  C_13
```

Your cursor loop looks for `code = 'ABC' and ID != 3`, which finds IDs 1 and 2. So in the first iteration of the loop up update the rows with ID 1, so now you have:

```
ID_STUDENT  ID_COURSE
----------  ---------
         1          3
         1          2
```

Then in the second iteration you try to update the rows with ID 2, which would **attempt** to produce:

```
ID_STUDENT  ID_COURSE
----------  ---------
         1          3
         1          3
```

which would break the unique constraint - hence the error.

You probably don't want to create a new course at all, but either way, you need to remove duplicate records from `student_course` - that is, rows which will become duplicates when updated. Basically you need to find students with entries for both existing course IDs, and delete either of them. If you don't care which this would do it:

```
delete from student_course sc1
where id_course in (
  select id
  from course
  where code = 'C_13'
)
and exists (
  select null
  from student_course sc2
  join course c on c.id = sc.id_course
  where sc2.id_student = sc1.id_student
  and sc2.id_course > sc1.id_course
  and c.code = 'C_13'
);
```

but there are other (probably better) ways.

You then have the choice of updating all remaining junction records for both old IDs to your new ID; or to consolidate on one of the old IDs and remove the other.

(Your question implies you want to solve the overall task yourself, so I'll refrain from trying to provide a complete solution - this just hopefully helps you understand and resolve your main problem...)

Comment: I believe inside `exists` there should be an axtra check `and sc2.ID_COURSE IN (select id from COURSE where code = 'C_13')` otherwise it would delete every reference in the junction table (but I want exactly one per duplicated course). I'm more than grateful for your help Sir, thank you.

Comment: Yes indeed, or with a join. I  thought I'd done that but clearly forgot and tested it too briefly on too small a data set, sorry. This is why you shouldn't blindly run code off the internet *8-) Glad you noticed...